# Regex match items in property list

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes that have a property that is a list of strings.

I would like to do some regex matching on the strings in the list, for example to match all strings that are like `JVM_.*`.

I know I can do an exact match like this:

```
match (f:File)
where "JVM_OPTS" in f.env
return f.id,f.path,f.env
```

but I don't see anything in the docs that would allow me to do something like in

```
match (f:File)
where "JVM_.*" ~ f.env
return f.id,f.path,f.env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that `any` of the items in the list matches your expression and return the file only if one matches, you can do something like this :

```
MATCH (f:File)
WHERE ANY(x IN f.env WHERE x =~ 'JVM.*')
RETURN f.id, f.env


╒══════╤══════════════════════════════╕
│"f.id"│"f.env"                       │
╞══════╪══════════════════════════════╡
│123   │["JVM_OPTS","JAVA_HOME","CWD"]│
└──────┴──────────────────────────────┘
```

If you're interested to return the file in any case and return the items in the list that match your expression, you can do this instead :

```
MATCH (f:File)
RETURN f.id AS id, [x IN f.env WHERE x =~ 'JVM.*'] AS env

╒════╤════════════╕
│"id"│"env"       │
╞════╪════════════╡
│123 │["JVM_OPTS"]│
└────┴────────────┘
```